# Can we change date format in Moment js

Tags: jquery, momentjs

In moment js if date format `moment().format(Do MMM YYYY)` then this will show date like `15th Mar 2018`.

How can i get result like `MONDAY, THE 15TH DAY OF JANUARY, 2018 AT 11:00 AM` in this format by using moment js.

Comment: What is your input? What did you tried so far?

Comment: Sir i use X-editable Combodate, i want to view format 
MONDAY, THE 15TH DAY OF JANUARY, 2018 AT 11:00 AM

Comment: Check out this http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 1):

You can get your answer like:

```
moment().format(dddd, [THE] Do [DAY OF] MMMM, YYYY [AT] HH:mm a z)
```